# Automatically deleting objects older than n days in Amazon S3 (How ?)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, amazon-s3, amazon-web-services

I am storing many images in Amazon S3,
using a ruby lib (http://amazon.rubyforge.org/)

I don't care the photos older than 1 week, then to free the space in S3 I have to delete those photos.

I know there is a method to delete the object in a certain bucket:

```
S3Object.delete 'photo-1.jpg', 'photos'
```

Is there a way to automatically delete the image older than a week ?

If it does Not exist, I'll have to write a daemon to do that :-(

Thank you

---

UPDATE: now it is possible, check the Roberto's answer.

Comment: there is a better answer then the marked one...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, Amazon doesn't offer an API for automatic deletion based on a specific set of criteria.

You'll need to write a daemon that goes through all of the photos and and selects just those that meet your criteria, and then delete them one by one.

Comment: Warning! - check out @Roberto's post below. It can be done now.

Answer (score 45):

You can use the **Amazon S3 Object Expiration policy**

[Amazon S3 - Object Expiration | AWS Blog](http://aws.typepad.com/aws/2011/12/amazon-s3-object-expiration.html)

> If you use S3 to store log files or other files that have a limited
>   lifetime, you probably had to build some sort of mechanism in-house to
>   track object ages and to initiate a bulk deletion process from time to
>   time. Although our new Multi-Object deletion function will help you to
>   make this process faster and easier, we want to go ever farther.
>
> S3's new Object Expiration function allows you to define rules to
>   schedule the removal of your objects after a pre-defined time period.
>   The rules are specified in the Lifecycle Configuration policy that you
>   apply to a bucket. You can update this policy through the S3 API or
>   from the AWS Management Console.

[Object Expiration | AWS S3 Documentation](http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/ObjectExpiration.html)

> Some objects that you store in an Amazon S3 bucket might have a
>   well-defined lifetime. For example, you might be uploading periodic
>   logs to your bucket, but you might need to retain those logs for a
>   specific amount of time. You can use using the Object Lifecycle
>   Management to specify a lifetime for objects in your bucket; when the
>   lifetime of an object expires, Amazon S3 queues the objects for
>   deletion.

*Ps: Click on the links for more information.*

Answer (score 1):

If you have access to a local database, it's easy to simply log each image (you may be doing this already depending on your application), and then you can perform a simple query to retrieve the entire list and delete them each. This is much faster than querying S3 directly, but does require local storage of some kind.