# Is it possible to automatically delete objects older than 10 minutes in AWS S3?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

We want to delete objects from S3, 10 minutes after they are created. Is it possible currently?

Comment: Use cron job to delete files from S3

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Automatically deleting objects older than n days in Amazon S3 (How ?)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3237742/automatically-deleting-objects-older-than-n-days-in-amazon-s3-how)

Comment: The above question is for deleting objects older than 'n' days, and we are in search of an answer, if it's feasible to delete objects older than '10' minutes.

Comment: Please clarify: why would this be useful?  There is probably a straightforward solution that will solve your actual problem, but it isn't going to be object expiration (lifecycle policies) for reasons I will explain (which go beyond the configuation limitations).

Comment: Following is the use case: We are generating PDFs and storing in S3, for clients to download in realtime after PDF are stored. These PDFs are not needed after they are downloaded to clients, so we need to delete after max of 10 minutes.

Comment: Did you find a solution? I'm struggling with this as well.

Comment: I'm also struggling with this too.

Comment: @chickensoup  please see my solution below using AWS services.

Comment: @Tibidabo please see my proposed solution below to remove s3 objects after a 10 minute delay.

Comment: @Justinas - see serverless solution below.

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot - see my solution below.  Can work for objects created and up to 15 minute limit.  This is a limit on the sqs queue delivery delay.

Comment: @Taterhead yep, that will do it. +1

Comment: See below for another serverless solution involving AWS Step Functions.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I have a working solution that was built serverless with the help of AWS's [Simple Queue Service](https://aws.amazon.com/sqs/) and [AWS Lambda](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/welcome.html).  This works for all objects created in an s3 bucket.

### Overview

When any object is created in your s3 bucket, the bucket will send an event with object details to an SQS queue configured with a 10 minute delivery delay.  The SQS queue is also [configured to trigger a Lambda function](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSSimpleQueueService/latest/SQSDeveloperGuide/sqs-configure-lambda-function-trigger.html).  The Lambda function reads the object details from the event sent and deletes the object from the s3 bucket.  All three components involved (s3, SQS and Lambda) are low cost, loosely coupled, serverless and scale automatically to very large workloads.

### Steps Involved

1. Setup your Lambda Function First.  In my solution, I used Python 3.7.  The code for the function is:

   ```
   import json
   import boto3

   def lambda_handler(event, context):

   for record in event['Records']:
       v = json.loads(record['body'])
       for rec in v["Records"]:

           bucketName = rec["s3"]["bucket"]["name"]
           objectKey = rec["s3"]["object"]["key"]
           #print("bucket is " + bucketName + " and object is " + objectKey )

           sss = boto3.resource("s3")
           obj = sss.Object(bucketName, objectKey)
           obj.delete()

   return {
       'statusCode': 200,
       'body': json.dumps('Delete Completed.')
   }
   ```

This code and a sample message file were uploaded to a [github repo](https://github.com/thomasbtatum/CodeForSO40904782).

2. Create a vanilla SQS queue.  Then configure the SQS queue to have a 10 minute delivery Delay.  This setting can be found under Queue Actions -> Configure Queue -> 4 setting down

[image]

3. Configure the SQS Queue to trigger the Lambda Function you created in Step 1.  To do this use Queue Actions -> Configure Trigger for Lambda Function.  The setup screen is self explanatory.  If you don't see your Lambda function from step 1, redo it correctly and make sure you are using the same Region.
4. Setup your S3 Bucket so that it fires an event to the SQS Queue you created in step 2.  This is found on the main bucket screen, click Properties tab and select Events.  Click the plus sign to add an event and fill out the following form:

[image]

Important points to select are to select `All Object create events` and to select the queue you created in Step 2 for the last pull down on this screen.

5. Last step - Add an execute policy to your Lambda Function that allows it to only delete from the specific S3 bucket.  You can do this via the Lambda function console.  Scroll down the Lambda function screen of your console and configure it under `Execution Role`.

This works for files I've copied into a single s3 bucket.  This solution could support many S3 buckets to 1 queue and 1 lambda.

Comment: Nice solution. A cheaper alternative might be to use AWS Step Function with an initial wait state of 10 minutes. See https://docs.aws.amazon.com/step-functions/latest/dg/tutorial-cloudwatch-events-s3.html and https://docs.aws.amazon.com/step-functions/latest/dg/amazon-states-language-wait-state.html

Comment: if you create obj1 and right after 9 minutes you create obj2 in the same bucket, after one minute , with this method  the lambda function will delete only obj1 or every object within the bucket ?

Comment: only obj1.  See code above.  10 minutes after obj2 is created, obj2 will get deleted.

Answer (score 4):

In addition to the detailed solution proposed by @taterhead involving a SQS queue, one might also consider the following serverless solution using [**AWS Step Functions**](https://aws.amazon.com/step-functions/):

- Create a State Machine in AWS Step Functions with a [Wait state](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/step-functions/latest/dg/amazon-states-language-wait-state.html) of 10 minutes followed by a [Task state](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/step-functions/latest/dg/amazon-states-language-task-state.html) executing a Lambda function that will delete the object.
- Configure CloudTrail and CloudWatch Events to [start an execution of your state machine when an object is uploaded to S3](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/step-functions/latest/dg/tutorial-cloudwatch-events-s3.html#tutorial-cloudwatch-events-s3-step-1).

It has the advantage of (1) not having the 15 minutes limit and (2) avoiding the continuous queue polling cost generated by the Lambda function.

Inspiration: [Schedule emails without polling a database using Step Functions](https://winterwindsoftware.com/serverless-email-scheduler/)

Comment: In the solution above, the lambda doesn't poll the queue.  The queue triggers the lambda.  All is fine as long as the messages are dequeued and your lambda doesnt error out.

Comment: There is a continuous polling: _There are no additional charges for this feature, but because the Lambda service is continuously long-polling the SQS queue the account will be charged for those API calls at the standard SQS pricing rates._ from https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/aws-lambda-adds-amazon-simple-queue-service-to-supported-event-sources/

Comment: It's not a "real" trigger like SNS. Agree this is poorly documented but if you check your bills you will see the effect of having Lambda "triggered" by SQS queues. They are basically polling for you behind the scene and if the queue grows they start more functions.

Comment: While long polling seems to create ca. 648.000 SQS requests per month (5 instances polling every 20 seconds), you'd still be in the free tier with a single queue and pay ca. $0.26 per month ($0.40 per million requests) per polled SQS queue outside of the free tier. Depending on the use case, AWS State Functions may be more expensive than that. At $0.025 per 1,000 state transitions, the break-even is ca. 10,000 state transitions per month. Deleting 1 object every 10 minutes is already 4,320 state transitions per month.

Answer (score -2):

If anyone is still interest in this, S3 now offers Life Cycle rules which I've just been looking into, and they seem simple enough to configure in the AWS S3 Console.

The "Management" tab of an S3 bucket will reveal a button labeled "Add lifecycle rule" where users can select specific prefixes for objects and also set expiration times for the life times of the objects in the bucket that's being modified.

For a more detailed explanation, AWS have published an article on the matter, which explains this in more detail [here](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/amazon-s3-object-expiration/).

Comment: Downvoted because at the time of this answer, Life Cycle rules cant fire in less than 1 day intervals.  OP wants a 10 minute delete solution.