# Delete Objects from S3 Buckets after 30 minutes not working

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda, aws-step-functions

I have seen this post: [amazon web services - Is it possible to automatically delete objects older than 10 minutes in AWS S3? - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40904782/is-it-possible-to-automatically-delete-objects-older-than-10-minutes-in-aws-s3)

It says to delete after 10 minues and which is working fine for me using Amazon SQS but we have a limit of max 15 minutes. Now I am trying using Step Functions.

I created a State Machine to trigger a Lambda function with a wait time of 1800 seconds and in task state I gave Lambda ARN, see below Lambda:

```
import json
import boto3

def lambda_handler(event, context):

for record in event['Records']:
v = json.loads(record['body'])
for rec in v["Records"]:

    bucketName = rec["s3"]["bucket"]["name"]
    objectKey = rec["s3"]["object"]["key"]
    #print("bucket is " + bucketName + " and object is " + objectKey )

    sss = boto3.resource("s3")
    obj = sss.Object(bucketName, objectKey)
    obj.delete()

 return {
'statusCode': 200,
'body': json.dumps('Delete Completed.')
}
```

I have enabled CloudTrail and added S3 bucket in bucket option and other bucket in storage option. Then I created CloudWatch Event for Object Level Monitoring to trigger step function which I created in first Step.

Now issue is with Lambda, It is not able to fetch events from Step Function about bucket name and object. Can anyone help here?

Comment: If the original 10-minute version using Amazon SQS is working for you, why not simply change the delay to 15 minutes?

Comment: So your problem is in retrieving the Bucket name and Key? When Amazon S3 Events sends the notification, it includes this information in the message, which comes through the `event`. Since you are using Step Functions, you'll need to find a way to preserve that information to pass through the the Lambda function.

Comment: I need for 30 minutes, max is 15min for delay, anyway I got it working, Some issue was there with the syntax